# Объясните, пожалуйста, что происходит во втрой строке

Tags: java, char, null, return

```
private static Character getCharByPosition(char[] charArray, int position){
    return charArray.length<=position ? null : charArray[position]; //эта строка мне совершенно не понятна
}
```

Comment: спросили бы в комментарии - я бы ответил. это называется тернарный оператор. сначала идет условие charArray.length<=position потом вопросительный знак. после вопросительного знака до двоеточия указывается выражение, которое исполнится, если условие правдивое, а после двоеточия, если условие ложное. таким образом, если charArray.length<=position, то вернется null, если же это условие не выполнится, то вернется charArray[position];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return charArray.length<=position ? null : charArray[position];
```

Эта строка равнозначна:

```
if (charArray.length <= position) {
    return null;
} else {
    return charArray[position];
}
```

т.е. краткий синтаксис тернарного оператора if

Comment: Большое спасибо!